# Как проверить что объект {} не пустой?

Tags: javascript

Как правильно проверить в JavaScript, является ли объект пустым, или содержит какие-то свойства?

Comment: Что значит "пустой"?

Comment: var object = {}

Comment: @IonDen спасибо за правки )

Comment: Загляните в [библиотеку lodash, функция _.isEmpty](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isEmpty). А вот [как она реализована](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/isEmpty.js)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Например так:

```
if (Object.keys(obj).length == 0) {
    console.log('пуст');
}
```

Но к сожелению, `Object.keys()` доступен [не везде](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Object.keys) (нужно отметить галочку *Show obsolete browsers?* для того, чтобы увидеть все браузеры), поэтому можно воспользоваться [полифилом](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), либо такой, например, функцией:

```
function isEmptyObject(obj) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Либо так при помощи jQuery, если Вы не изменяли прототип `Object`:

```
if ($.isEmptyObject({});) {
     console.log('пуст');
}
```

Comment: У jQuery код в данном случае не впечатляет: `{for(var b in a)return!1;return!0}` - если что-то было добавлено в прототип всех объектов, то ни один объект пустым не будет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, согласен, но метод есть как факт) Изменил немного ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ,  _Object.keys(obj).length_ по моему лучший вариант. НО свойство _keys()_ был добавлен в **ECMAScript 5.1** , а до этого как можно было бы проверить?

Comment: @Rolandius http://stackoverflow.com/a/18913060/1988244 - может стоит дописать в ответ, хотя бы краткую версию?

Comment: @PashaPash, да-да, пишу сейчас)

Comment: @Riskey, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Rolandius красава :)

Comment: @Rolandius "Но к сожелению, Object.keys() доступен не везде" -- по вашей ссылке http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Object.keys  написано, что везде =)

Comment: @dzhioev, там надо выставить галочку на *Show obsolete browsers?* для того, чтобы видеть старые браузеры (допишу в ответе). Увы, красивей и читабельней сравнительных таблиц поддержки я еще не видел...

Comment: @Rolandius, если объект имеет много полей, то `isEmptyObject` будет работать очень уж не эффективно. Не проще ли возвращать `false` сразу же, как только у объекта найдено первое собственное свойство?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, согласен, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
if(!JSON.stringify({a:7})=='{}'){
 console.log('Не пуст')
}
```

Или проверить наличие третьего символа в строке, пустой объект-строка всегда имеет 2 символа.

```
 if(JSON.stringify({a:7})[2]){
   console.log('Не пуст')
 }
```

Comment: Полегче с нецензурными словеками

Comment: Ну и вариант этот тоже не очень сам по себе т.к. там могут быть пробелы и табуляции или же так называемые рыбы.

Comment: Duoxx,точно! Но это для тех, кто привык не ставить пробелы изначально. Пусть будет так )

Comment: По-моему JSON.stringify доступен везде. И мы, т.о., получаем самое короткое выражение (я про второе исполнение), верно? Но обращение [2] может запутать

Comment: Ваш подход напоминает мне использование `if (String(var).length == "5")` вместо `if (!var)`. Зачем переводить объект в строковое представление, если можно просто спросить его о наличии полей, как сделал Rolandius?

Comment: Arhad, спасибо! Вариант Rolandius будет быстрее из-за отсутствия преобразований?

Comment: Да. Если Rolandius пробегает только по самому объекту, останавливаясь на первом полноценном атрибуте, то `stringify` обрабатывает весь объект, рекурсивно переходя по каждому объектному атрибуту.

Comment: Arhad, спасибо! Сами знаете, это стремление к коротким выражениям ))

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно вот так

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var key in obj)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const isEmpty= Object.keys(obj).length == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Переделал код из [ответа @Роландиуса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454974):

```
Object.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
  for(let i in this) if (this.hasOwnProperty(i)) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Чтобы вызывать у любого объета:

```
{a: {b: "c"}}.isEmpty()
```

или:

```
["a", "b", "c"].isEmpty()
```

Comment: `{a: {b: "c"}}.isEmpty()` - ошибка `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'`